# Set static external IP for my load balancer on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to set up a static external IP for my load balancer on GKE but having no luck. Here is my Kubernetes service config file:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: myAppService
spec:
  selector:
    app: myApp
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 3001
    targetPort: 3001
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: *********
```

This doesn't work. I expect to see my external IP as ********* but it just says pending:

```
➜  git:(master) kubectl get services
NAME         CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes   *********    <none>        443/TCP          5m
myAppService   *********   <pending>     3001:30126/TCP   5m
```

More details:

```
➜  git:(master) kubectl describe services
Name:           kubernetes
Namespace:      default
Labels:         component=apiserver
            provider=kubernetes
Annotations:        <none>
Selector:       <none>
Type:           ClusterIP
IP:         *********
Port:           https   443/TCP
Endpoints:      *********
Session Affinity:   ClientIP
Events:         <none>


Name:           myAppService
Namespace:      default
Labels:         <none>
Annotations:        <none>
Selector:       app=myApp
Type:           LoadBalancer
IP:         *********
Port:           <unset> 3001/TCP
NodePort:       <unset> 30126/TCP
Endpoints:
Session Affinity:   None
Events:
  FirstSeen LastSeen    Count   From            SubObjectPath   Type        Reason              Message
  --------- --------    -----   ----            -------------   --------    ------              -------
  5m        20s     7   service-controller          Normal      CreatingLoadBalancer        Creating load balancer
  5m        19s     7   service-controller          Warning     CreatingLoadBalancerFailed  Error creating load balancer (will retry): Failed to create load balancer for service default/myAppService: Cannot EnsureLoadBalancer() with no hosts
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13):

This got me stuck as well, I hope someone finds this helpful.

In addition to what [Dirk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51323242/340888) said, if you happen to reserve a global static IP address as oppose to a regional one; you need to use Ingres as describe here in documentation: [Configuring Domain Names with Static IP Addresses](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip#step_2b_using_an_ingress) specifically step 2b.

So basically you reserve the static ip `gcloud compute addresses create helloweb-ip --global`

and add an Ingres:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: helloweb
# this is where you you add your reserved ip
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: helloweb-ip 
  labels:
    app: hello
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: helloweb-backend
    servicePort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: helloweb-backend
  labels:
    app: hello
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: hello
    tier: web
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
```

The doc also describe how to assign a static ip if you choose type "LoadBalancer" under step 2a.

Comment: Same issue I ran into, global static IP, but with Ingress I can't seem to get IP whitelisting working

Answer (score 11):

I've encountered the same problem, but after reading the docs carefully, it turned out that I was just reserving the static IP incorrectly.
A service of type `LoadBalancer` creates a network load balancer, which is regional. Therefore, also the static IP address you reserve needs to be regional also (in the regoin of your cluster).
When I changed to this solution, everything worked fine for me...

Comment: How you did the changes? Can you share the steps?

Answer (score 0):

To use a static IP address in your kubernetes service, you need to first [reserve the IP address in GCP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#gcloud).

Next ensure your GKE cluster has the HttpLoadBalancing addon is enabled in your cluster.

You can now create a kubernetes service of type LoadBalancer with a loadBalancer IP address equal to the reserved IP.

To learn more check out the [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/service-load-balancer). You can also see other methods of exposing your applications in the documentation.